iOS notification doesn't show the image?
I’m working on a Flutter app and have integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications. The push notifications are working fine on iOS, and I’ve connected APNs as well. However, the notifications do not display images on iOS devices.
To resolve this, I’ve added a Notification Service Extension as a target in my Xcode project, but the images still don’t show up in the notifications. What could be causing this issue, and how can I get images to display correctly in iOS notifications?
For Flutter iOS I connected firebasemessag. APNS is also connected, it is also working. But it doesn't show pictures on IOS. For this I added Notification Service Extension as a target
